# can I use "used to" for something is "used for" some objective?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I am curious about using "used to" which is used for expressing some habitual actions in the past. But how to use it for passive voices?

**Example 1:**

I used to eat chocolate too much when I was a baby

This example is OK. What about the second one?

**Example 2:**

a) This computer is used to calculate statistics.

b) This computer is used for calculating statistics.

Which one is more suitable? In other words, are both of them give the same meaning? I am avoiding making contextual mistakes.

My problem is that I have read a sentence and I thought it should be corrected:

**Actual sentence:**

Bivariate linear regression is used to measure the degree of linear relationship between two variables.

**After correction (not sure if it is really required):**

Bivariate linear regression is used for measuring the degree of linear relationship between two variables.

I think **(b)** should be.

Comment: You are having trouble with the verb forms "used to [do something]" **versus** "to be used for something". They are completely different from each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al of your sentences are correct.

Note that in your (a) and (b) sentences, 'The computer is used' is the passive of 'X uses the computer'. It has nothing at al to do with the 'used to' for past habitual action.

Comment: + More precisely, it *no longer* has anything to do with *used to* for past habitual action. Well into the 18th century *use* was employed in this sense in the present tense, too.

Answer (score 3):

Your example 1 would be pronounced 'Yoost'
Example 2 as 'Yoozed'.
It's quite difficult to confuse the two given the context of the whole sentence, even if both are in the same sentence.

*'I used to be terrible at spelling until I used a dictionary'*

As for ***used to*** Vs ***used for***, both are ok unless there is ambiguity, i.e.

*The greyhound is used to running.*  It is familiar with the act of running.
*The greyhound is used for running.* Running is the dogs function.

Both versions of your Bivariate sentence are contexually and grammatically correct so it's down to personal preference.

Comment: +1 for that all-important point about pronunciation. I asked about the related *have/haff to [do something]* myself, over three years ago. It was pointed out to me then that *use* and *suppose* have also undergone this kind of change. If you forget about the largely irrelevant *written* form, these words have effectively spawned "new" words with significantly different meanings, which are *never* confused with the "original" in speech. But I didn't consciously register that difference between OP's examples 1 & 2 until I scrolled down to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

So the word "used" is a form of past, "use" is now or  future.  <Both, not at once>

"to"   would be the know of past-past

"for", the now or of Object used for subjects.

"Of"  Future contents. Given explanations.

I  "to" be confused, "for" wrong subjective teaching, "of" once thought process... [(Use)]
,......

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is completely incomprehensible. Can you try to write proper sentences?